# Access to pointers inside __eq meta method?

Tags: lua, meta-method

I have Lua objects which share a metatable which has a `__eq` metamethod. Inside this meta method, I want to check if the two objects are the same object before even comparing them. Similar to how in java you would do `a == b || a.compareTo(b)`. The issue though is by doing `==` inside of `__eq`, it calls `__eq` and thus Stack Overflow. How can I achieve this?

```
local t1 = { x = 3 }
local t2 = { x = 3 }
local t3 = t1
print(t1 == t3) -- true, they pointer to same memory
local mt = {
    __eq = function(lhs, rhs)
        if lhs == rhs then return true end -- causes stack overflow
        return lhs.x == rhs.x
    end
}
setmetatable(t1, mt)
setmetatable(t2, mt)

-- stack overflow below
print(t1 == t2) -- this should compare 'x' variables
print(t1 == t3) -- this shouldn't need to do so, same memory location
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to test for equality inside the `__eq` metamethod because Lua only calls the `__eq` metamethod if the userdata pointers are different.

Add `print(t1 == t3)` right after setting the metatables to confirm this.

The [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4) says (emphasis added):

> `__eq`: the equal (==) operation. Behavior similar to the addition operation, except that Lua will try a metamethod only when the values being compared are either both tables or both full userdata and **they are not primitively equal**.

Comment: Ah wow I should have given metamethods more credit to be smart enough to do that. Putting a print inside the `__eq` proves this to be true. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Check `rawequal()` function. It will compare instances without calling metamethods.